# Adding new data from JSON to existing table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-table

I am trying to add new data (from JSON) to existing table (using jquery).

In my html I have this table for example:

```
<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive" data-column-btn-text="Filter Columns" id="MyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-priority="1">A</th>
      <th data-priority="2">B</th>
      <th data-priority="3">C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
      <td>c1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

I am trying to do this (for adding new data from JSON):

```
var response = [{
      "A":"a2",
      "B":"b2",
      "C":"c2"
     },
     {
      "A":"a3",
      "B":"b3",
      "C":"c3"
    },
    {
      "A":"a4",
      "B":"b4",
      "C":"c4"
    }];

    $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                $('<tr>').html(
                //"<tr>" +
                "<td>" + response[i].A + "</td><td>" + response[i].B + "</td><td>" + response[i].C + "</td>" + "</tr>").appendTo('#MyTable');
        });
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Do you agree that if you append to `#MyTable` the new elements will be out of `tbody` or `thead` elements ?

Comment: yes I am agreeing with you. and I do not know how to changing / fixing it.

Comment: use `item.A` instead of `response[i].A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending the content to the table itself and not to the `thead` or `tbody` elements, which is what should be done. Try changing your selector in `.appendTo` to `#MyTable tbody` and it will work. [Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ppdnd/)

Answer (score 0):

You were accessing the object in wrong way.Try this code snippet.

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
                    $('<tr>').html(
                      "<td>" + item.A + "</td><td>" + item.B + "</td><td>" + item.C + "</td>" + "</tr>").appendTo('#MyTable tbody');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  $('<tbody>').append instead of $('<tr>').html().

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
    $('<tbody>').append(
    "<td>" + response[i].A + "</td><td>" + response[i].B + "</td><td>" + response[i].C + "</td>" + "</tr>").appendTo('#MyTable');
});
```

You can see it in action at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qAb9/).

Comment: Why not acces object like `item.A` instead of `response[i].A`? What if you have two `tbody` in DOM?

Comment: No particular reason not to do it that way, I just copied the code from the question with the minimal changes to help him see the difference. Your answer way is just as good.

Comment: I believe it's best to show OP the best practise too. Though it's just my personal opinion :)

Comment: No disagreement here, I just didn't take the time to do it in this case. Good on you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet. This creates the 'tr' elements in the html.

```
    $.each(response, function(i, item) {
$("#MyTable tbody").append("<tr> <td>" + response[i].A + "</td><td>" + response[i].B + "</td><td>" + response[i].C + "</td>  </tr>");                 
            });
```

Comment: Why not acces object like `item.A` instead of `response[i].A`?

Comment: It makes no difference. I just have it there since that's what the question had.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
table_html = '';
$.each(response, function(index, value) {
table_html += "<tr><td>"+value["A"]+"</td><td>"+value["B"]+"</td><td>"+value["C"]+"</td></tr>"   
        });
```

Give some id to `<tbody>` tag.

```
$("tbodyid").html(table_html);
```